# htaccess if URL contains string redirect to page without changing URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a URL like `example.com/product-name.html`.

I want to redirect any URLs that contain the string `html` to `search.php` but I want to keep the original URL that was typed in, so if `example.com/product-name.html` was redirected to `search.php` it should still show `example.com/product-name.html` in the browser.

I am using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} html
RewriteRule .* search.php
```

Which redirects but does not keep the original typed URL in the browser.

How can I do this?

Comment: Those two lines don't redirect. The redirection happens somewhere else. You should show your entire .htaccess.

Comment: Try using `RewriteRule (.*) /search.php [L]` and see if that works for you

Comment: "Which redirects but does not keep the original typed URL in the browser." - What URL do you see in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule html search.php [NC,L]
```

If it does not work, you have another problem in .htaccess (Please indicate it in full in your question) or config.
Start by clearing your cache before testing. Or try with another browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Proxy RewriteRule** and **mod_proxy**

`RewriteRule "/(.*)\.html$" "/search.php" [P]`

Make sure to enable and configure mod_proxy properly. mod_proxy documentation can be found [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).